# How to append all rows of all columns of a dataframe below the last row of first column

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
        0                            1                       2                       3
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}     {'id':10:'age':33}        {'id':10:'name':'Paul'} {'id':10:'name':'Paul'} 
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}     {'id':10:'age':'Paul'}    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'} {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}     {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}   {'id':10:'name':'Paul'} {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}     {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}   {'id':10:'name':'Paul'} None
```

So, in this example I have 4 columns with 4 rows.  Happens that my dataframe has 500 rows and 7 columns, something around 3500 records (there are a few `none` on column 7)

All rows in all columns are dict type, even though they can be different or not

**What I need:** How can I transform this dataframe to have only 1 column, by placing all row of column 1 below that last row of column 0 an so on untill all rows of the last column has been placed below the last row of column 0 ?

**Expected Result:**

```
         0
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}             
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}         
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}      
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}     
{'id':10:'age':33} 
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
{'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
more rows
None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), and keep only the value column:

```
df.melt(value_name=0)[[0]]
```

output:

```
                          0
0   {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
1   {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
2   {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
3   {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
4        {'id':10:'age':33}
5    {'id':10:'age':'Paul'}
6   {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
7   {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
8   {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
9   {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
10  {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
11  {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
12  {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
13  {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
14  {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
15                     None
```

Comment: worked! but gives me this warning: `FutureWarning: This dataframe has a column name that matches the 'value_name' column name of the resulting Dataframe. In the future this will raise an error, please set the 'value_name' parameter of DataFrame.melt to a unique name.`

Comment: Which pandas version do you have? This doesn't do it with the latest 1.4.2 and it shouldn't be an issue as all columns are used here ;)

Comment: I see, I had `'0'` (string) as column name, you can use `df.melt()[['value']].rename(columns={'value': df.columns[0]})` to avoid the warning. It's weird that the warning is raised when the column with same name is used in the melt (it's normal if it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

```
ss11=pd.Series()
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    global ss11
    ss11=pd.concat([ss11,ss])
df1.apply(function1)
ss11.pipe(print)

0    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
1    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
2    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
3    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
0         {'id':10:'age':33}
1     {'id':10:'age':'Paul'}
2    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
3    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
0    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
1    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
2    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
3    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
0    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
1    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
2    {'id':10:'name':'Paul'}
3                       None
```